# Class-File-Editor.Source-not-found Source Attachment Doesn't Have Source-File ReflectionUtils.class

Tags: maven-3, m2eclipse, eclipse-jdt, decompiler, debug-mode

## What are the details of your problem?

I'm unable to decompile-debug on Eclipse like I expect. I'm used to IntelliJ and its decompiling-debugger and I thought I had the [Eclipse JDT (Java Development Tools)](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/eclipse.jdt) working with this at one point, but seems I'm either misremembering or this isn't the tool I'm thinking of. The project builds fine and runs but doesn't resolve the go-into actions for its dependencies like I remember, IntelliJ and other IDE-Plugins provide (regardless of language).

How do I get Eclipse to recognize the rest of the Maven Dependency Packages I built with but Eclipse-Debugger can't resolve at Debug-Runtime?

```
**Class File Editor** 

**Source not found**
The source attachment does not contain the source for the file ReflectionUtils.class.
You can change the source attachment by clicking Change Attached Source below: 

[Change Attached Source...] 

// Compiled from ReflectionsUtils.java (version x.x : x.x, super bit)
public abstract class org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils {
```

## What did you try and what were you expecting?

I've tried changing the `Eclipse.Preferences` and `Eclipse.[Project].Properties` and making sure they're set.
I've checked for `Java.Build-Path.Source-and-output-folder` for both "Project" and "Folders" with `Source folder name: src` & `Output folder name: bin`.
And, I made sure `As JRE library use: JRE container` rather than the `JRE_LIB variable (deprecated)`.

Checked that `Eclipse.Preferences.Java.Build-Path.Classpath-Variables` existed. As well as, looked into `Java.Build-Path.User-Libraries` but couldn't find a valid option that the `New...` or `Import...` would accept.
But even when I'm prompted to `Change Attached Source...` and I provide it the direct JAR location, the instance still doesn't resolve even upon restart.
This is even more perplexing because upon reselection, the field is already populated with the correct info.

The `Eclipse.[Project].Properties.Java-Build-Path.Libraries` has `Maven Dependencies` directly listed and toggled-open show the exact JAR files that the runtime-debugger claims to not know the source to resolve to. And this libraries has the correct JDK because the same `Workspace default JRE` is used that the project build with as well. `Eclipse.Java-Build-Path.Order-and-Export` In've explicitly selected `Maven Dependencies` and moved to the `Top` so that these would be the first to resolve for the project.

I've left the entire rest of the project to default and toggled no `Enable project specific settings` to make sure that there wasn't any JDK or Maven versioning discrepancies. They're all set to use the same as `Workspace-Defaults / Eclipse-Preferences`. `Eclipse.Preferences.Maven.User-Settings` are set to the default install locations +> `Global Settings (open file): C:\Users\[User.name]\.m2\settings.xml`, `User Settings (open file): C:\Users\[User.name]\.m2\settings.xml`.

Is this just how Eclipse works? If I can't download any plugins for this project and permissions are restricted.

Comment: You describe in detail what you have done but I am missing the basic information about the project you are in. Also what "go-into actions" are you talking about? May some screenshots would be helpful to see what you are trying to do. BTW: AFAIR Eclipse has no built-in decompiler so for external dependencies that have no src package published via Maven Eclipse won't be able to show you anything except the byte code.